# Finding general solution of this algebric equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

Do this equation  $x^a-y^b=2$ where $x,y,a,b\in\mathbb{I}$ has a general solution or all solutions of it are random? Here $x$ and $y$ are variables and $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: Which ones are parameters and which one are indeterminates?

Comment: I guess you can parametrise it as $x=(2+y^b)^{1/a}$

Comment: every integral y will not give integral x, so we have to chose y delibrately